# How to solve video and mouse issues on HP Pavilion A288N?

Tags: drivers, mouse, hp, gpu-driver

I am trying to get an HP Pavilion A288N desktop to run 12.04, but display is bad and mouse acts like an 'eraser'. It has an integrated ProSavageDDR (KM266) graphics card.

I'm running already Windows XP on it with the latest driver from S3; SP23964 (VIA/S3 graphics driver v6.14.10.0012 update). However, XP has no problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command first:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

to install display drivers. This will fix your display.

Comment: No. It will install utilities, it won't fix any driver issue. Without actually using the utilities this answer is worthless.